# SubView click item to show in parent view label

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to make a UI that have label, table view and one button click. When click on the button, we pop up a half screen view that have lots of buttons.  I want user can still click on the rest of the screen also.

So i use the approach that suggest in the post
[How To Present Half Screen Modal View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907662/how-to-present-half-screen-modal-view)

Method 2:  to animate a UIView which is of size half of the existing view.
           Then you have to simply follow animation of the UIView.
Here as it is just a UIView that will be added as subview to existing view, you will be able to touch the rest of the screen.

As i am newbie to the ios and swift, I would like to get some suggestions. 
Now i am successfully add as subview and show in the half of the screen.

How can i implement to let subview click button result show on parent view label text?

I am thinking about parent.xib and subview.xib have the same UIVeiwController.swift. Then i can @IBOutlet and @IBAction to the same controller swift file and update the result. But don't know it is the accpetable way to do?

If not, how can the subViewController send result/event to the parent view and update in the parent view component?

Answer (score 1):

You could use delegation.  This keeps your view controllers decoupled, i.e. prevents the child from having a reference to its parent, which allows other view controllers to interact with the modal view controller in the same way.

```
class ParentViewController : UIViewController, ModalViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let modalViewContorller = ModalViewController()
        modalViewContorller.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController( modalViewContorller, animated: true, completion: nil )
    }

    func modalViewControllerDidProduceResult( modalViewController: ModalViewController, result: String ) {
        self.label.text = result
    }
}

protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate {
    func modalViewControllerDidProduceResult( modalViewController: ModalViewController, result: String )
}

class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: ModalViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonClicked( sender: AnyObject? ) {

        delegate?.modalViewControllerDidProduceResult( self, result: "Hello!" )
    }
}
```

You could also use a closure, which in Swift provides a more concise syntax.

```
class ParentViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let modalViewContorller = ModalViewController()
        self.presentViewController( modalViewContorller, animated: true, completion: nil )
        modalViewContorller.resultBlock = { (result: String) in
            self.label.text = result
        }
    }
}

class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

    var resultBlock: ((String) -> ())?

    @IBAction func buttonClicked( sender: AnyObject? ) {

        self.resultBlock?( "Hello!" )
    }
}
```